# How to use multiple screens on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: multiple-monitors

How can I get two screens show half and half of my desktop? On Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: It's usually the same, plug in the monitor and Ubuntu will do it for you. But, you may need graphics drivers or specific instructions for specific systems. Can you tell us a bit more about your computer? Namely, what kind of CPU and Graphics Card do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe combining displays is supported by default.

You can extend the display and then remove the launcher by going into settings -> displays.

After that you will have 2 screens that you can use.  Sometimes you even need to turn off display mirroring if that is enabled.

[image]